# Is it true that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n^{1/n}$ exists, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} {x_{n+1}\over x_n}$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Is it true that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n^{1/n}$ exists, $\lim_{n\to\infty} {x_{n+1}\over x_n}$ exists.

Prove or give a counter example.

I think it is false, but I can't search a counter example.

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste problem :)

Answer (score 4):

A simple counterexample is $(x_n) =(1,2,1,2,1,2,\ldots)$.

For any real number $c>0$, $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{c} = 1$, thus $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n^{1/n} =1$, but on the other hand $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ alternates between 2 and $\frac{1}{2}$